# ZigBee Light Link product with custom gateway

Tags: zigbee, philips-hue

**Background information**

The company where I do my internship is developing a smart home cloud solution with it's focus on B2B. We have already connected several LoRa and EnOcean products to our cloud that are working fine. Now our PR department would like to have a connection with Philips Hue for demonstration purposes.

As some might know, all Philips Hue devices are connected to a bridge using ZigBee (Light Link protocol). One can interact with the lamps using the rest API that is provided by the bridge.

We have an Rexense RG4100 ZigBee/WiFi gateway. Our idea is to remove the Philips Hue led ligths from their bridge and connect them directly to the Rexense gateway. The gateway will have an open connection to our server that we can use to control the lights. We already tested the Rexense gateway and came to the conclusion that it is possible to keep an open connection with our server and that the ZigBee gateway is working (we can send AT commands and receive a response).

**Problem**

Our problem is is that we don't know how we can connect the Philips Hue lights to our Rexense gateway. While searching the internet, I found several articles. Some say it's possible, some say it's not. (for example: [Direct ZigBee communication with Philips Hue Smart Light Bulbs](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/196372/direct-zigbee-communication-with-philips-hue-smart-light-bulbs))

I also found another article saying that it is possible, but that you need a master key. The only option to get this masterkey would be by joining the ZigBee Alliance, which will cost a minimum of $4000 each year.

Philips is also creating a remote API to access the bridge from outside a WiFi network. This would be the easiest option, but unfortunately it is still in a testing phase and it is not yet announced when the remote API will be available.

**Question**

My main question is: is it possible to connect the Philips Hue lamps to a custom (Rexense RG4100) gateway?

If yes, I would like some help on how to do this. Some articles on explaining it would be awesome! (I could't find these, but perhaps I didn't use the correct search terms).
Do we also need the master key to get this done?

Thanks for any information!

Comment: Have a look at [this article](https://peeveeone.com/?p=135) for some info about keys and commissioning. There are several other interesting articles about Zigbee Light Link on that blog as well.